# Debian KVM host and guests interfaces configuration

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, interface

I've got dedicated Debian server with Proxmox as KVM manager and such IP example network:

```
IP address  175.19.59.209
Netmask     255.255.255.224
Gateway     175.19.59.193
```

Now I'm trying to configure subnets with such topology:

```
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
\\Gateway 175.19.59.193\\
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
 \
  +----------+
  | KVM-host |
  | eth0     |
  | vmbr0    |
  | vmbr1    |
  +----------+
    |
    |  +------+    +------+       +------+
    +--| vm01 |----| vm02 |--/ /--| vm09 |
       +------+    +------+       +------+
```

That's how my **host** machine interface is configurated now:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address  175.19.59.209
    netmask  255.255.255.224
    gateway  175.19.59.193
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
    address  10.10.11.1
    netmask  255.255.255.0
    bridge_ports none
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
```

And this is guest machine **vm01** configuration:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.10.11.12
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.10.11.1
```

The problem is that I can't ping **vmXX** out of host *vice versa*. Also I have no idea how to route vm01:80 to the Internet and back to make vm01 reverse proxy for 10.10.11.0/24 network.

What have I missed? Any advice for the networking "newby"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Ensure vmbr1 contains the tap devices for each VM:

```
brctl add vmbr1 tapX
```

2) Ensure iptables on the host allows bridge traffic:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged -j ACCEPT
```

3) Ensure you allow NAT via vmbr0:

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: 1) With your help I've found wrong tap device name (I've set it **vmbr1** and now it's **netX** device)